# HasPrecision(9,6) not know for entityframework configurations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Could someone give me a reason as to why I'm not able to use the .HasPrecision() method on properties in my ef code first model. Example below

```
public class Location
{
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Long { get; set; }   
}

using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
public class LocationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Location>
{
    public LocationConfiguration()
    {

        Property(x => x.Long).HasPrecision(9,6);
        Property(x => x.Lat).HasPrecision(9,6);

    }
}
```

In the Above example configuration method 'HasPrecision(9,6)' is unknown and I can't seem to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Lat` and `Long` have type `double`, but `HasPrecision` is for `decimal` properties. Do you want to save them in the database as a decimal type, or as a binary floating-point type? If the former, change the property types. If the latter, you can get rid of `HasPrecision`.

Comment: How right you are... been staring myself blind on it and totally missed the datatype. Thanks.